# Represent Classes in JSON

Tags: arrays, json, categories

I try to implement Transaction Classes into a JSON file. For an Example...

```
Holidays [Flights, Hotels, etc.]
Groceries [Drinks, Food]
Transportation [Car Taxes, Car Insurance, rental car, petrol]
```

How would i manage to do so?

Could i define two classes and link them with IDs?

```
   categoryList: [
        {
            name: 'Holidays',
            id: 1000
        },  {
            name: 'Groceries',
            id: 1001
        },  {
            name: 'Transportation',
            id: 1002
        }
    ],
    subCategoryList: [
        {
            name: 'Flights',
            categoryId: 1000
        },  {
            name: 'Hotels',
            categoryId: 1000
        },  {
            name: 'Drinks',
            categoryId: 1001
        }, {
            name: 'Food',
            categoryId: 1001
        }, {
            name: 'Car Taxes',
            categoryId: 1002
        }, {
            name: 'Car Insurance',
            categoryId: 1002
        }, {
            name: 'Rental Car',
            categoryId: 1002
        }
    ]
```

I've bank transactions and would like to classify them by category's within my app.

Comment: JSON is a language-neutral data interchange format. You cannot 'implement' *anything* in it really. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Voting to close this. As far as I can tell this isn't a question, it's a request for a complete tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am supposing that you think in JavaScript, and...
Yes! you can!

I think the best way is create an array in each object with subelements:

```
   categoryList: [
        {
            name: 'Holidays',
            subelements: ['Flights', 'Hotels']
        },  {
            name: 'Groceries',
            subelements: ['Drinks', 'Foods']
        },  {
            name: 'Transportation',
            subelements: ['Car Taxes', 'Rent a Car']
        }
    ],
```

Also, if you want detailed subelement you could create a object array instead a string array:

```
   categoryList: [
        {
            name: 'Holidays',
            subelements:  [{
                name: 'Flights',
                optional: false 
            },  {
                name: 'Hotels',
                optional: true 
            }]
        }, ... ]
```

But if you will have sub a lot of sub-elements repeated take only one property to identify, like name or ID and search details in an array for detailed sub-element.

I am supposing that you think in JavaScript, and...
Yes! you can!

I think the best way is create an array in each object with subelements:

```
categoryList: [
    {
        name: 'Holidays',
        subelements: ['Flights', 'Hotels']
    },  {
        name: 'Groceries',
        subelements: ['Drinks', 'Foods']
    },  {
        name: 'Transportation',
        subelements: ['Car Taxes', 'Rent a Car']
    }
 ],
```

Also, if you want detailed subelement you could create a object array instead a string array:

```
categoryList: [
        {
            name: 'Holidays',
            subelements:  [{
                name: 'Flights',
                optional: false 
            },  {
                name: 'Hotels',
                optional: true 
            }]
        }, ... ]
```

But if you will have sub a lot of sub-elements repeated take only one property to identify, like name or ID and search details in an array for detailed sub-element.

### Alternative solution

And, I think the most simple way is changing categoryList array:

```
categoryList: [ 'Holidays', 'Groceries', 'Transportation' ]
```

Now you got a auto-numbered array, so: 0 -> Holidays 1 -> Groceries 2 -> Transportation

Then, you have to change the subCategoryList:

```
subCategoryList: [
    {
        categoryId: 0, name: 'Flights' }, {
        categoryId: 0, name: 'Hotels' }, {
        categoryId: 1, name: 'Drinks' }, {
        categoryId: 1, name: 'Food' }, {
        categoryId: 2, name: 'Car Taxes' }, {
        categoryId: 2, name: 'Car Insurance' }, {
        categoryId: 2, name: 'Rental Car' }
]
```

Now, every time you need the name of a category go to the array, for example:

```
for(var i=0 ; i < subCategoryList; i++){
    console.log('for ' + subCategoryList[i].name + ', category is: '
    + categoryList[ subCategoryList[i].categoryId ] );
}
```

Comment: Thx! That was exactly what i was looking for!
Sry, i'm new to js and could't really formulate my question properly.

Comment: How would i add a different language to this?

Comment: You can use any language, i used JS because is easy for my and very famous, but you could transform the JSON in any language with a library or create your to adapt your JSON Array into C# List or Java HashSet, or anything.